# CSS "right" property is not consistent between objects

Tags: css, html, iframe, web

So, for a website, I have the site divided up with divs and iframes: an iframe for a sidebar, an iframe for a footer, and a big div in the middle for the body content.  In order to get everything static and well-fitting, I used the code here:

```
.bodycontent{
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:150px;
right:0px;
bottom:100px;
overflow:auto;
}

.footerframe {
position:fixed;
left:150px;
bottom:0px;
right:0px;
height:100px;
border-top: 2px solid #888;
border-right: 2px solid #888;
border-top-right-radius:4px;
}
```

This was intended to get both the main div and the footer iframe to stretch across the page.  It works for the main div, but not the footer.  What is up with that inconsistency?

Comment: I shouldv'e added that I've tried width:100%.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1. Top/Bottom or Left/Right should be used in pairs always, not in four values. If you use top, don't use bottom; if you use left don't use right.
2. If you want an element with position fixed to stretch to the whole page, you should give it `width:100%`

:)

Comment: I've tried.  `width:100%` gives me overflow off the side of the page, because (my monitor is 1280px wide) the browser recognizes the 100% as 1280, but then adds the 150px margin, throwing the edge off the page.

Comment: Why don't you add an element inside the fixed one and give that element the margin?